# Oracle SQL Insert external values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having problems to add some values to a table. The query that i'm using is this one:

```
INSERT INTO ACTUAR
(CAPITULO,TEMPORADA,COD_GRUPO,COD_LOC)
SELECT NUM_CAP,NUM_TEMPO,CODIGO_GRUPO,CODIGO_LOC
FROM COMENTAR
MINUS
SELECT CAPITULO,TEMPORADA,COD_GRUPO, COD_LOC
FROM ACTUAR;
```

The `ACTUAR` table has 2 more values, which I want to add from a value on `COMENTAR` like this:

```
NVL(SUBSTR(COMENTARIO,0,10),'SIN PROBLEMA'),
NVL(SUBSTR(COMENTARIO,LENGTH(COMENTARIO)-4),'SIN SOLUCION')
```

**Actuar** table

```
CAPITULO,TEMPORADA,COD_GRUPO,COD_LOC,PROBLEMA,SOLUCION
```

**Comentar** table

```
NUM_CAP,NUM_TEMPO,CODIGO_GRUPO,CODIGO_LOC,COMENTARIO
```

I want to put the first 10 chars of `COMENTARIO` on `ACTUAR'S PROBLEMA` and the last 4 on `ACTUAR'S SOLUCION` or the text in the nvl if they are null.

I want to insert the result of the minus operation on **ACTUAR** plus the 10 first chars of **COMENTARIO** from **COMENTAR** into **ACTUAR'S PROBLEMA** and the last 4 on **ACTUAR'S SOLUCION**

The desired result should be something like

**ACTUAR**

CAPITULO,TEMPORADA,COD_GRUPO, and COD_LOC the values from the minus operation.

PROBLEMA - first 10 chars of COMENTAR COMENTARIO

SOLUCION - last 4

Comment: These are values or additional columns.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  You seem to be suggesting that you want columns from the second table in a `MINUS` . . . which doesn't make sense, because those records are being removed by the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me. I used `merge` statement, without `update` clause.

```
merge into actuar a
using (
  select num_cap, num_tempo, codigo_grupo, codigo_loc, 
      nvl(substr(comentario,1,10),'SIN PROBLEMA') prob,
      nvl(substr(comentario, greatest(length(comentario)-4, 1)),'SIN SOLUCION') sol
    from comentar) c
on (a.capitulo = c.num_cap and a.temporada = c.num_tempo
  and a.cod_grupo = c.codigo_grupo and a.cod_loc = c.codigo_loc)
when not matched then insert (a.capitulo, a.temporada, a.cod_grupo, 
    a.cod_loc, a.problema, a.solucion)
  values (c.num_cap, c.num_tempo, c.codigo_grupo, c.codigo_loc, c.prob, c.sol)
```